How do different countries treat barely legal adults having sex with minors?
The case of an 18-year-old being jailed because he had sex with a 17-year-old in Dubai, where the age of consent is 18, has recently made British news because both were Londoners and a British group called Detained in Dubai is campaigning to have the 18-year-old freed.
I couldn't find any laws or historical precedents for what happens when similar cases happen in the UK - i.e. when the age of consent is 16 and a 16-year-old has sex with a 15-year-old. Are there any such cases, or do the police/CPS generally just decide not to prosecute? I'm also interested in answers for jurisdictions outside of the UK.

Many jurisdictions have what are called "Romeo and Juliet" exceptions to their statutory rape laws. https://sex-crimes.laws.com/statutory-rape/romeo-and-juliet

The law is varied
england-and-wales
The basic crime is spelled out in s9(1) of the Sexual Offences Act 2003:

(1) A person aged 18 or over (A) commits an offence if—
(c) either—
(i) B is under 16 and A does not reasonably believe that B is 16 or over, or
(ii) B is under 13.

So, a 16-year-old can legally engage in sexual activity with a 15-year-old. But an 18-year-old can’t — unless they reasonably believe the 15-year-old is at least 16.
But, under s16, if the over 18 is in a position of trust the age is raised from 16 to 18.
In addition, prosecutorial discretion applies. So, a just 18-year-old having sex with an almost 16-year-old when they have been in a sexual relationship for a long time, is unlikely to cause a prosecutor to prosecute.
new-south-wales
There is no similar rule in Subdivision 5 of Division 10 of the Crime Act 1900. Anyone that engages in sexual conduct with someone under 16 (17 for relationships of trust) has committed the offence — even if they are both under age.
Of course, prosecutorial discretion is still a thing.

I'm glad the UK has a "she had a fake ID" clause, at least.

Until some years ago, the age if consent in the UK for gay sex was 18 years, not 16 years. As a consequence, a male couple both below 18 couls have sex, not quite legal but they were too young to be punished. Then on the 18th birthday of the older one it became highly illegal sex with a minot, until the 18th birthday of the younger one. So with a month age difference, a couple had to put having sex on hold for a month.

france
France has two thresholds to deal with this: 15 and 18 years of age. It is forbidden for someone over 18 to have sex with someone under 15. It is therefore not forbidden for a 17-year-old to have sex with a 14-year-old or for a 20-year-old to have sex with a 17-year-old.
There is also a specific criminal offense punishing adults for having sexual relationships with minors between 15 and 17 when they have “authority” over them or are “abusing their position”. This would for example make it illegal for teachers, coaches, etc. to engage in sexual activity with a minor irrespective of the age gap or any notion of coercion.

united-states
In the United States, these are colloquially known as “Romeo and Juliet laws” - laws that allow consent between two people if they are close enough in age, even if one is slightly above the age of consent and the other is slightly below.
About two-thirds of states have Romeo and Juliet laws. The specifics of the law vary by state.

germany
In Germany, there are three relevant age limits for the age of consent:

under 14: sexual acts involving a child under 14 are a crime - StGB § 176 Sexueller Missbrauch von Kindern. However, even in this case there is an exception if the age difference is small.
under 16: Between 14 and 16, a minor may consent to sexual acts, but it may still constitute a crime if the older participant is over 21 and "exploits the victim’s lack of capacity for sexual self-determination" - § 182 Sexueller Mißbrauch von Jugendlichen. Also, this is only prosecuted on demand (Antragsdelikt)
under 18: Sexual acts constitute a crime if the older participant is in a position of caregiver or authority (e.g. school teacher, athletic coach, boss...) - § 174 Sexueller Mißbrauch von Schutzbefohlenen

Note that all the above only applies for consensual activities not involving payment of money. If coercion or even force is involved, the penalties are higher.
